# How to extract values of multiple listboxes on Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, forms, userform

I have a userform with multiple checkboxes and listboxes, where each checkbox controls the values of one listbox each.

After clicking on 'Next' the userform inputs the selected values of each listbox on the Excel sheet. I am able to achieve this only for one pair of checkbox and listbox at a time. But I want the results of each shortlisted items one after the other.

```
Private Sub cmdFDB_Next_Click()
Dim ColCount As Integer, lastrow As Integer
Dim lastrow1 As Integer
Dim Data As Integer
Dim i As Integer

lastrow = Worksheets("Model Portfolio").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

With Worksheets("Model Portfolio").Cells(lastrow, 2)

    .Offset(2, 0).Value = "Fixed Deposits and Bonds"
    .Offset(2, 0).Font.Bold = True
    .Offset(2, 0).Font.Size = 12

    For i = 2 To lastrow

        If Me.chkGB.Value = True Then
            .Offset(3, 0).Value = "Government Bonds"
            .Offset(3, 0).Font.Bold = True
            .Offset(3, 2).Value = Format(Me.txtGB.Value, "Currency")
            lastrow1 = lastrow + 4
            ColCount = 2
            With Me.lbxGB
                'loop through each listbox item to see if they are selected
                For Data = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                    If .Selected(Data) = True Then
                        Cells(lastrow1, ColCount).Value = .List(Data)
                        lastrow1 = lastrow1 + 1
                    End If
                Next Data
            End With
        End If

        If Me.chkCFD.Value = True Then
            .Offset(3, 0).Value = "Corporate Fixed Deposits"
            .Offset(3, 0).Font.Bold = True
            .Offset(3, 2).Value = Format(Me.txtCFD.Value, "Currency")
            lastrow1 = lastrow + 4
            ColCount = 2
            With Me.lbxCFD
                'loop through each listbox item to see if they are selected
                For Data = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                    If .Selected(Data) = True Then
                        Cells(lastrow1, ColCount).Value = .List(Data)
                        lastrow1 = lastrow1 + 1
                    End If
                Next Data
            End With
        End If

        If Me.chkTSB.Value = True Then
            .Offset(3, 0).Value = "Tax Saving Bonds"
            .Offset(3, 0).Font.Bold = True
            .Offset(3, 2).Value = Format(Me.txtTSB.Value, "Currency")
            lastrow1 = lastrow + 4
            ColCount = 2
            With Me.lbxTSB
                'loop through each listbox item to see if they are selected
                For Data = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                    If .Selected(Data) = True Then
                        Cells(lastrow1, ColCount).Value = .List(Data)
                        lastrow1 = lastrow1 + 1
                    End If
                Next Data
            End With
        End If

    Next i
End With

With MultiPage1
    .Value = (.Value + 1) Mod (.Pages.Count)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Could not understand use of `For i = 2 To lastrow` loop. Value of i never used. Also it seems data form 1st List box is being overwritten by the next next List box box values as `LastRow1` is always calculated as `lastrow1 = lastrow + 4`. If For i loop is really uncalled for then, may increment LastRow with 4 each Checkbox = True and increment by 1 for each selected value of the list box (assumed multi select). It would be of help to help,  if image of desired  output data is provided.

Comment: Posted an answer to your question how to extract selected listbox data; consider to accept as solved if helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Extract selected listbox items to sheet**

As you aren't consequent in your row numbering (never changing lastrow mixed with additional offsets and increments), you are loosing track of the actual row numbers.
It's also better practice to use a Sub procedure (here: `WriteItems`) for repetitive calls and to redefine your lastrow (here: start row) each time. Furthermore I demonstrate how to extract a whole listbox "row" using the `Application.Index()` function.

*Further hint:* Instead of direct formatting, consider to use conditional formatting (CF) as you needn't clear old formats in deleted cells (sure you find a lot of examples at SO :-)

*BTW I'd prefer to avoid control names containing an underscore "_" as this has some relevance in class implementations.*

**Main event**

```
Private Sub cmdFDB_Next_Click()
'[0] Define data sheet
     Const SHEETNAME As String = "Model Portfolio"
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SHEETNAME)
'[1] Define abbreviations to identify securities controls
     Dim Abbreviations, abbr
     Abbreviations = Array("", "GB", "CFD", "TSB")  ' first item is EMPTY!

'[2] write data for each security type
     Dim OKAY As Boolean
     For Each abbr In Abbreviations
        '[2a] check
        If abbr = vbNullString Then                 ' Main Title
            OKAY = True
        ElseIf Me.Controls("chk" & abbr) Then       ' individual security checked
            OKAY = True
        Else
            OKAY = False
      End If

    '==================================
    '[2b] write selected data in blocks
    '----------------------------------
          If OKAY Then WriteItems abbr, ws            ' call sub procedure
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Next

End Sub
```

**Sub procedure `WriteItems`**

```
Private Sub WriteItems(ByVal abbrev As String, ws As Worksheet)
'Purpose: write caption and selected listbox items to sheet
'Note: called by cmdFDB_Next_Click()
Const EMPTYROWS As Long = 1        ' << change to needed space
Const LBXPREFIX As String = "lbx"  ' << change to individual checkbox prefix
Const TITLE     As String = "Fixed Deposits and Bonds"

With ws
    '[0] Define new startrow
    Dim StartRow As Long
    StartRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + EMPTYROWS + 1
    '[1] Write caption
    ws.Cells(StartRow, 2) = getTitle(abbrev) ' function call, see below
    If abbrev = vbNullString Then Exit Sub   ' 1st array term writes main caption only

    'other stuff (e.g. formatting of title above)
    '...

    '[2] Write data to worksheet
    With Me.Controls(LBXPREFIX & abbrev)
        Dim i As Long, ii As Long, temp As Variant
        For i = 1 To .ListCount
            If .Selected(i - 1) = True Then
                ii = ii + 1
                ws.Cells(StartRow + ii, .ColumnCount).Resize(1, 2).Value = Application.Index(.List, i, 0)
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End With
End Sub
```

*Further note:* The `Application.Index` function allows to get a whole listbox "row" by passing zero (..,0) as second function argument.

**Helper function `GetTitle()`**

```
Function getTitle(ByVal abbrev As String) As String
'Purpose: return full name/caption of security abbreviation
Select Case UCase(abbrev)
    Case vbNullString
         getTitle = "Fixed Deposits and Bonds"
    Case "GB":  getTitle = "Government Bonds"
    Case "CFD": getTitle = "Corporate Fixed Deposits"
    Case "TSB": getTitle = "Tax Saving Bonds"
    Case Else:  getTitle = "All Other"
End Select
End Function
```